# Conga Composer IF statement with static text and merge field?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to show or hide fields and their identifying static field based on if the field in Salesforce is blank or not. My IF statment is shown below:

```
`{{ IF {{OPPORTUNITY_LINEITEM_CREATIVE_SIZES}} <> “” “Creative Sizes: {{OPPORTUNITY_LINEITEM_CREATIVE_SIZES}}” “” }}`
```

[Image of what the entire block looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5oY5.png)

Unfortunately even if the "Creative Sizes" field is blank it will still pull in the bolded static text identifier. Please help! I've been trying different things for almost 4 hours now and I'm going insane!

Comment: Are you sure `OPPORTUNITY_LINEITEM_CREATIVE_SIZES` is null? Can you look at the debug values?